# Does numpy have a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I am creating 2 sinusoidal waves in python in order to test some algorithms and specially, measure and fix some delays between phases. It's supposed to be simulating mains voltage and current

```
from math import *
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 60
fs = f * 144 
sample = fs

def wave(peakv, peaki, angle = 0):
    x = np.arange(sample)

    vrms = 0
    irms = 0

    rads = 2 * np.pi
    if angle == 0:
        angulo = 0
        offset = 0
    else:
        angulo = 360 / angle
        offset = rads / angulo

    tcoffset = - rads * 6/ (360) #+ 1 * error * rads /360

    offset = offset - tcoffset 

    v = peakv * np.sin(2*np.pi*x/fs) * 1.5035 + 0.6
    i = peaki * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / fs - offset) * 1.92 * 20 + 0.15
    #rms
    vrms = np.sqrt(np.dot(v, v)/sample)
    irms = np.sqrt(np.dot(i, i)/sample)
    #power
    S = vrms * irms
    Pa = 0
    Pa = np.dot(v, i)

    Pa /= sample
    PF = Pa/S
    print '------------------------------------------'

    print 'Vrms = ', vrms
    print 'Irms = ', irms

    print 'Apparent power = ', S #* (angle * pi / 180)
    print 'Power = ', Pa
    print 'Power factor = ', PF
    print 'theta = ', np.arccos(PF) * 180 / np.pi

    print '************************************************'
    print
    print 'Using calibration ... '
    #Calibrsating gain and offset
    gv = (peakv/sqrt(2))/vrms
    gi = (peaki/sqrt(2))/irms

    ov = (max(v) + min(v))/2
    oi = (max(i) + min(i))/2

    v = gv * v - ov * gv
    i = (gi * i - oi * gi)

    #
    prev = 0

    #applying allpass filter
    vout = np.arange(sample)
    iter = 0
    vout = [0] * sample
    for n in np.nditer(v, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        vout[iter] = n - 0.99332 * (n - vout[iter-1]) + prev
        prev = n
        #vout[iter] *= 0.49
        iter += 1
    v = vout

    vrms = np.sqrt(np.dot(v, v)/sample) / 149.84
    irms = np.sqrt(np.dot(i, i)/sample)

    S = (vrms * irms)
    newp = np.dot(i, v)/sample / 149.84
    newPF = newp/S

    print 'Corrected theta allpass   = ', np.arccos(newp/S) * 180 / np.pi

    print 'Calibrated Voltage        = ', vrms
    print 'Calibrated Current        = ', irms
    print 'Calibrated Apparent Power = ', S
    print 'Calibrated Active power   = ', newp
    print 'Calibrated Power Factor   = ', newPF

    print '------------------------------------------'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = sqrt(2)

    wave(127*r, 5*r, 70)
```

This is supposed to correct a phase offset added by a current transformer in different power factors. It works @60°, from 0-50 and 90° ... for some reason when you put 51, 52, 53, ... it calculates the exact same angle between the 2 phases and from 61-72 and then in the 80's it alos gives the exact same value.

My title is misleading since I know that the probability that there is an error in numpy is very very low, but I'm out of ideas, when I test it with most values it works without a hitch, I can even plot them with much problem and they seem to be ok. My problem is with those values ... I really don't know what's happening, maybe a rounding problem with the np.sin function?

Comment: Sounds like you have an integer division somewhere you haven't realized. Using `from __future__ import division` would mostly force division to be floating-point. If this is the problem, you may want to be more careful about your data types in the future.

Comment: @user2357112 I thought so .... you are absolutely right ... I didn't know you could do what you suggested ... and also it's my first time doing "real" calulations in python .. I simply VERY WRONGLY assumed it would do floating point calculations. If you want you can add your comment as an answer and get the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer but forgot to reply here.

The most important thing is that the variable x is wrong, it's not supposed to be an np.arange(sample), this gives you an array from 0 to sample, which is just wrong. After I saw that I realized I was doing it wrong ... I simply did that because  I use arange a lot and I ended up using it this way ... so I corrected to x = np.arange(0, 1/f, 1/Ts), where Ts = 1/fs. After I did that everything started working perfectly.

So ... a note for everyone, even if it's something you use/do daily, think before you just use/do it like you always do, some times you will prevent bugs and save yourself a few days of debugging